# painting a Long Text at LABELFIELD?

Tags: blackberry

I have a long text for LabelField. But LabelField doesn't show all. I dont know how to fix it, what should I do?

I am using default labelfield.

```
manager
            .add(new LabelField(
                    "IP kameranıza hemen bağlanmak için\n Ana Menüdeki \"Kameralarım\""
                            + "butonuna tıklayınız. Açılan sayfadaki menüden \n\"Yeni Ekle\"yi seçip "
                            + "kameranızın modelini, IP numarasını, port numarasını varsa kullanıcı adı ve şifresini "
                            + "girip kayediniz. Eğer video server kullanıyorsanız \"Server Numarası\" "
                            + "alanına izlemek istediğiniz kameranın numarasını(1,2,3 vb.) giriniz. "
                            + "Normal bir IP kamera kullanıyorsanız \"Server Numarası\" alanını boş bırakınız. "
                            + "Kamera listesinden istediğiniz kamerayı seçip menüden \"Izle\" seçeneğini "
                            + "seçerek kameranızı izlemeye başlayabilirsiniz.Tam Ekran izlemek için "
                            + "telefonunuzu yatay konumda tutunuz. Kameranızın PTZ özelliği varsa "
                            + "ekranda görünen butonları kullanabilirsiniz.",
                    DrawStyle.HCENTER | USE_ALL_HEIGHT)
```

Comment: Are you customizing LabelField or using default LabelField? Can u give some sample coding?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [TextField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TextField.html) instead of a [LabelField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/LabelField.html)